# docker ports are not accessible

Tags: .net, docker

One silly question. However i cannot answer ...

I have a few running containers
[image]

Here is DockerFile -

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerAgain.dll"]
```

I used this command for creating containers

```
docker run -p 4004:80 from_command_line
```

**Problem**

Browser returns "not found" error for http://localhost:4004
Why ? And how i can fix this ?
Port inside container is exposed, port redirecting is set ... i am confused and disappointed

Comment: try with this ```http://0.0.0.0:4004```

Comment: @juliansalas Unfortunately the same

Answer (score 1):

First thing to test is to check if your application is available inside the container with

```
docker exec <container id> [nc|curl|telnet|wget|whatever-you-got] localhost:80
```

Nevertheless one common reason that your application is not available outside the container, is that your application is by default map on localhost eth, and not available to request from outside the container.

I don't know much asp.net but you have to map your application to interface `0.0.0.0`

Comment: thank you for hint. As i see application is not available inside container ... i got error "container XXX encountered an error during CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2) extra info: ..."